# Populate Textbox based on another Textbox MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to populate textbox value based on another textbox but i cannot populate the the other textbox. i'm sharing my code please guide me with best solution

Action Method:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetInfo(string Email)
        {

            var result = (from c in db.Customers
                          where c.Email.ToLower().Contains(Email.ToLower())
                          select new { c.FirstMidName }).Take(6);

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var Email;
            $(function () {
                $("#Email").keydown(function () {
                    Email = $("#Email").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'Admin/Ticket/GetInfo',
                        data: { Email: Email },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                $('#Phone').text(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

i have searched internet but couldn'd find any suitable solution. please guide me with this

Comment: Why are you using document-ready handler inside document-ready handler?

Comment: @Satpal i have tried removing this but i'm still getting the same problem

Comment: what is the error is ajax call going?

Comment: Nothing strikes me as error-prone in the things you've currently posted (except for maybe the double `document.ready`, but you said that's fixed). Could you elaborate on what happens when you try it? Does the ajax call get sent out? Does it return? Do you get the alert? What error do you get?

Comment: can you show the response json?

Comment: you are getting 6 rows right

Comment: @Flater i'm not getting any error, i'm getting the JSON response successfully here it is "FirstMidName":"usama" but it is not binding to texbox this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Flater i'm not getting any error, i'm getting the JSON response successfully here it is "FirstMidName":"usama" but it is not binding to texbox this is the problem`

```
$('#Phone').text(data); //your code
```

The problem is that you're setting the text to `data`, but you've confirmed that `data` **has a field named FirstMidName** (in other words, `data` isn't a string!). Therefore, you should reference the field:

```
$('#Phone').val(data.FirstMidName); //my fix
```

**Edit** I also changed `.text()` to `.val()`. You should use the latter when working with form input elements.

Comment: Try to add the following to the `success` callback to see if your data is of the correct format: `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` this should shouw you your entire data object. `alert(data.FirstMidName)` this should show you the value you want. Can you confirm if both alert boxes show you what you're expecting?

Comment: Nevermind! Think I found it :) Use `$('#Phone').val(data.FirstMidName);` Notice I changed `.text()` to `.val()`.

Comment: i'm getting alert undefined

Comment: For which one? Doesn't really matter, but that mean that whatever you punt in the `alert` doesn't exist (or doesn't have any sort of value, think of it as `null`). So that means either your `data` object is empty, or it doesn't have a field named `FirstMidName`.

Comment: it is not empty i have tried putting the direct link in browser and download the json response file, can u tell me some other solution for this? like how i can populate other textbox value on the base of the current textbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54095/discussion-between-usama-sheikh-and-flater).

Answer (score 2):

you need to do like this and you have to use `val()` instead of `text()` to set the textbox value:

```
success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                alert(data.FirstMidName);
                                $('#Phone').val(data.FirstMidName);
                            }
```

also in your ajax call set **dataType**:

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'Admin/Ticket/GetInfo',
                        data: { Email: Email },
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data) {
                                alert(data.FirstMidName);
                                $('#Phone').val(data.FirstMidName);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

[**See FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k72RR/)

Comment: i'm not getting any alert

Comment: i have tried this before, i have clearly mentioned that i'm getting the json response successfully but cannot bind the value to textbox

Comment: IN alert can you see name?

Comment: No i just see undefined

Comment: you have missed datatype attribute of ajax set it to json like this: ``dataType:"json"``

Comment: u must know if as a developer that if there is no type defined then the default response is in "json" anyways your solution doesn't work

Comment: its weird, that its not working and i was not aware thanks for letting me know

Comment: do u have any other solution for this problem? i mean from a scratch

Comment: if alert is undefined that means the success function data is not gotten but in console you have response,, its illogical

Comment: it is not illogical it is something u don't know

Comment: in your select do like this to test:``return Json(new {FirstMidName=result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet})``

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with your problem and I am not sure if you managed to fix but just change.

```
$('#Phone').val(data.FirstMidName);
to
$('#Phone').val(data[0].FirstMidName);
```

The JSON result is an array so you have to use index. Hope this helps someone else.
Also in your controller Action you are requesting for more than one record you have to change to Take(1)